# Prove that $(D − A′)(C − B) + (D − B′)(A − C) + (D − C′)(B − A) = 0$.

Tags: geometry

Let $A, B, C, D$ be points in the plane, let $A′$ be the midpoint of $BC$, let $B′$ be the midpoint of $CA$, and let $C′$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Prove that
$$(D − A′)(C − B) + (D − B′)(A − C) + (D − C′)(B − A) = 0$$

I started by writing $A'$, $B'$, $C'$ in terms of $A$, $B$ and $C$ but it didn't seem to get me anywhere and have no other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Here the brute force method: Lets start with the middle points
\begin{align}
A'&=B+(C-B)/2\\\\
B'&=C+(A-C)/2\\\\\
C'&=A+(B-A)/2
\end{align}

Now lets calculate the 3 terms using this, assuming your product means the scalar product:
\begin{align}
(D − A′)\cdot(C − B)&=\frac{B_1{}^2}{2}-B_1 D_1+\frac{B_2{}^2}{2}-B_2 D_2-\frac{C_1{}^2}{2}+C_1 D_1-\frac{C_2{}^2}{2}+C_2 D_2\\\\
(D − B′)\cdot(A − C)& =-D_2 C_2-\frac{A_1{}^2}{2}+A_1 D_1-\frac{A_2{}^2}{2}+A_2 D_2+\frac{C_1{}^2}{2}-C_1 D_1+\frac{C_2{}^2}{2}\\\\\
(D − C′)\cdot(B − A)&=\frac{A_1{}^2}{2}-A_1 D_1+\frac{A_2{}^2}{2}-A_2 D_2-\frac{B_1{}^2}{2}+B_1 D_1-\frac{B_2{}^2}{2}+B_2 D_2
\end{align}
Now one can clearly see that all terms apear twice with different signs therefore the sum of the three terms vanishes.

Comment: I am a bit lost. How can points be subtracted and multiplied?

Comment: I calculated using two dimensional position vectors for example $A=(A_1,A_2)$. You add them by adding components and you do not multiply them, you use the scalar product: multiply the components and then sum up. There might be other ways without using vectors but I think the way I showed is straight forward.

Comment: So, A represents the vector OA? But is this a widely accepted notation?

Comment: Maybe using something like $\vec a=OA$ would be more appropriate but I wanted to keep the notation of the question (which is not to ideal since it does not even specify the scalar product). I mean in principle you do not even use the position vectors in that exercise directly since one is only interessted in difference vectors of the points. But appart from maybe notation the math should be ok.

Comment: Just wondering is the notation universal. This is because the question clearly stated “A, B, C, D (are) points” and then, points are subtracted (like C – B). I have no question about your math.

Comment: The only meaningfull way to "substract points" is subtracting their position vectors. But I would say a common/"proper" notation would be something like $\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$. So the equation above would read: $\vec{A'D}\cdot\vec{BC}+\vec{B'D}\cdot\vec{CA}+\vec{C'D}\cdot\vec{AB}=0$. The original notation is a bit sloppy but I guess there is only one way to understand it, so maybe it is common somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at coefficient of D, it is easy to see it is zero (=(B-C) + (C-A) + (A-B)).

Then the coefficient of "constant" is also zero by plugging in A' etc. and find them cancel out with each other.

$$A'(B-C) = (B^2-C^2)/2$$